# Which app for "B30 Wifi Video Doorbell" on Android 12?

Tags: android, iot

I recently changed my smartphone and my wifi doorbell does not work well anymore with the app Anyhome (no call when I put the app in background).
I tested others app but none succeeded to connect. Does anybody know if I can use another app? (an opensource one ideally)

Comment: Tangential to the question, but re: "*no call when I put the app in background*", perhaps you might be interested in [Don't kill my app!](https://dontkillmyapp.com/) to know more about the Android system's restriction and its possible solution.

Comment: Thanks Andrew T, your answer makes me find the solution, I have to authorize the window popup. You should directly answer the question to make me close it.

Comment: Thansks @AndrewT. , see my previous answer.

Comment: Since this site is about app recommendations, I'm not sure if my comment is suitable as an answer. Even if this was posted on [android.se], then my comment is just a link-only answer (since I don't know about the manufacturer and thus how to solve your case, though it's a comment suggestion for this issue in general), but your comment about "authorize the window popup" should be a valid answer.